# Kafka Stream and Table joins at different time intervals

Tags: join, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a very typical scenario where i need to perform cross joins between KStream from one topic at time t1 with KTable from another topic. To explain this I have come up with a diagram. Please refer the picture. I would like to understand if this is possible with Kafka Streams. I am pretty much aware that cross joins are possible. But, I would like to know if the joins are possible at different timeframes.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understand the question correctly, but you can "shift" time by providing a custom timestamp extractor:

```java
builder.table("topciName", Consumed.with(new MyTimestampExtractor()));

class MyTimestampExtractor implements TimestampExtractor { ... }
```

Comment: Hi Mathias, the scenario is the data can come to all the topics at different times. But, whenever a topic has new message the consumer should be able to join the incoming message with the datasets at the other two topics like how a streaming data joins with a static tables. Is this possible by a single consumer listening all the 3 topics using Kstream and KTable?

Comment: Using Kafka Streams, you can join multiple topics by doing multiple cascading join with 2 topics each. There is not out-of-the-box 3-way join operator (you could build a custom 3-way join as a `Transformer` though). Note, that a stream-table join is not symmetric, ie, it does only producer a result for stream inputs (table inputs only update the table). Thus, you would need to use KStream-KStream or KTable-KTable join. This might help: https://www.confluent.io/blog/crossing-streams-joins-apache-kafka/